# SQL display top 10 rows from multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, union

I am doing exercises on my own to understand how postgre SQL works, and this is about views. I am not able to complete this one, where I have to display the 10 biggest entities with the biggest radius (planets and satellites).

I have 3 tables:

planet:

```
 id |  name   | population | radius | period | id_system 
----+---------+------------+--------+--------+-----------
  1 | Mercury |          0 |   2439 |     88 |         1
  2 | Venus   |          0 |   6051 |    224 |         1
  3 | Earth   | 7000000000 |   6371 |    365 |         1
  4 | Mars    |          0 |   3389 |    687 |         1
  5 | Jupiter |          0 |  69911 |   4331 |         1
  6 | Saturn  |          0 |  58232 |  10747 |         1
  7 | Uranus  |          0 |  25362 |  30589 |         1
  8 | Neptune |          0 |  24622 |  59800 |         1
```

planetary_system:

```
 id | name  | star 
----+-------+------
  1 | Solar | Sun
```

and satellite:

```
id |   name    | radius | id_planet 
----+-----------+--------+-----------
  1 | Moon      |   1737 |         3
  2 | Titan     |   2576 |         6
  3 | Ganymede  |   2634 |         5
```

Expected output (sorted by radius DESC, name):

```
   type    | system |   name   | radius
-----------+--------+----------+--------
 planet    | Solar  | Jupiter  |  69911
 planet    | Solar  | Saturn   |  58232
 planet    | Solar  | Uranus   |  25362
 planet    | Solar  | Neptune  |  24622
 planet    | Solar  | Earth    |   6371
 planet    | Solar  | Venus    |   6051
 planet    | Solar  | Mars     |   3389
 satellite | Solar  | Ganymede |   2634
 satellite | Solar  | Titan    |   2576
 planet    | Solar  | Mercury  |   2439
```

My solution but I am lacking columns, how can I modify it?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_biggest_entities(system, radius_) AS
    SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT planet.radius, satellite.radius
        FROM planet, satellite) AS rad
    ORDER BY rad DESC
    LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_biggest_entities(object_type, system, name, radius) AS
select 'planet' object_type, ps.name system, p.name, p.radius
from planet p
inner join planetary_system ps on p.id_system = ps.id
union all
select 'satellite' object_type, ps.name system, s.name, s.radius
from satellite s
inner join planet p on s.id_planet = p.id
inner join planetary_system ps on p.id_system = ps.id
limit 10;
```

Comment: That was it! Could you explain what is 'system' in the first SELECT ps.name system ? EDIT: I have an error:  syntax error at or near "type"
LINE 2: select 'planet' type, ps.name system, p.name, p.radius

Comment: @catrev it's an alias, I've omitted `as`. Ok, let me check that error

Comment: @catrev the error was due to `type` being keyword in postgres, check out my edit